# realm react native null is not an object

Tags: react-native, realm

Follow the example from https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js:

realm.js:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

class Todo extends Realm.Object {}
Todo.schema = {
    name: 'Todo',
    properties: {
        done: {type: 'bool', default: false},
        text: 'string',
    },
};

class TodoList extends Realm.Object {}
TodoList.schema = {
    name: 'TodoList',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        creationDate: 'date',
        items: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Todo'},
    },
};

export default new Realm({schema: [Todo, TodoList]});
```

App.js:

```
import realm from './realm';
```

But I get this error:

```
null is not an object (evaluating '_NativeModules$Realm.debugHosts')
<unknown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use the object, not the class.

```js
const Realm = require('realm');

const Todo = {
    name: 'Todo',
    properties: {
        done: {type: 'bool', default: false},
        text: 'string',
    },
};

const TodoList = {
    name: 'TodoList',
    properties: {
        name: 'string',
        creationDate: 'date',
        items: {type: 'list', objectType: 'Todo'},
    },
};
const newRealm =  Realm.open({schema: [Todo, TodoList]})
export default newRealm;
```